# Is it advantageous to modify files with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, minify

I'm doing a web-app. It has about 10mb. Considering that I will use PhoneGap to install locally on a samsung Tablet, does it make sense minify the files (css, js, etc)? Surely it is better for decrease the internal memory of the device. But can you feel a difference in speed, for example going from page to page?

Comment: you will find the opinion rendered is incorrect. I would suggest looking at SPA (Single Page Apps). - Best of Luck

Comment: using $router of angular?

Comment: Yes. You might find *Ionic* of use. It appears to be a favorite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope - I don't think it would be perceptive to the user - I wouldn't worry about it :) Best just to decrease the file size of any images you use in app if you are concerned about saving space.